# What are the risks, if any, of upgrading GIMP from 2.8.16 to 2.9.x?

Tags: gimp, interface-design

I am interested in going to 2.9.4 for the added utility & improvements.  I have loads of custom scripts, UI, and so on that I use frequently, so these are my chief concerns - will they port ok?  GAP, G'MIC, FX-Foundry are the big ones.

Second q - the version release states it is production reliable, and that's good.  I just hate crashes.  How stable is it vs. 2.8.16?

Anything else I should be aware of?  Thanks.

Comment: The 2.9 versions are unstable development versions. You should be able to keep the 2.8 version. Can't see any reason why you shouldn't have both.

Comment: 2.9 is a development version, so something that you find important may stop working temporarily. GMIC has already a 2.9 version. AFAIK most scripts  still work but many elicit "deprecated" warnings (though these will disappear with 2.10). And I don't know how many can take advantage of the high-bit-depth mode.

Comment: However you can use 2.9 and 2.8 side by side. On Linux you'll find an "AppImage" for Gimp 2.9 (or you can compile Gimp/GEGL/BABL to run from /opt instead of /usr). For Windows Partha.com has "Portable" versions of 2.9 that can be used without installation.